# What is the proper type for Angular DI injected superagent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, superagent

I'm trying to inject Superagent in a node.js app which users Angular DI (ngx).

```
import * as request from 'superagent';
 ... 
 {
    provide: request,
    useFactory: () =>
      request.agent()
        .timeout({deadline: 10000, timeout: 60000}),
  },
```

But I get `property`timeout`does not exist on SuperAgent<SuperAgentRequest>`.  I tried following [these docs](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#agents-for-global-state) but the SuperAgent doesn't seem to be the correct type. The type of `request.agent()` should be `request.Request`.

What Am I missing? How do I properly provide `request.Request` so that I can configure it globally in order to use the same (injected) instance?

Comment: What is ngx, by the way?

Comment: ngx is new nomenclature for Angular 2-6...

Comment: Ah, sure, I supposed it was third-party lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can be seen in Superagent typings, `request.agent()` returns [`SuperAgent<SuperAgentRequest>` that doesn't have `timeout` method](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a0ca17240ae77638c933461a44acbf23739ce662/types/superagent/index.d.ts#L50-L79), this is what error message says.

While `timeout` method exists in [`Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a0ca17240ae77638c933461a44acbf23739ce662/types/superagent/index.d.ts#L114-L150) type that is a promise of a response. This is the reason why this error was thrown. There's no request and no response. [Superagent documentation](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#timeouts) provides an example for `timeout`:

```
request
  .get('/big-file?network=slow')
  .timeout({
    response: 5000,  // Wait 5 seconds for the server to start sending,
    deadline: 60000, // but allow 1 minute for the file to finish loading.
  })
```

The documentation states that agent instance has [methods that set defaults](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#default-options-for-multiple-requests), so typings are lacking. There is no `deadline` method, and it doesn't make sense with `timeout`, because this is deadline timeout .

`superagent` typings should be augmented locally, or be improved and PRed to DefinitelyTyped repository, or fixed in-place:

```
 {
    provide: request,
    useFactory: () =>
      <SuperAgent<SuperAgentRequest>>request.agent()
        ['timeout'](30)
  }
```

I would expect augmented typings to be something like (processed original `Request` interface with regular expression):

*custom.d.ts*

```
import * as request from 'superagent';

type CallbackHandler = (err: any, res: request.Response) => void;
type Serializer = (obj: any) => string;
type BrowserParser = (str: string) => any;
type NodeParser = (res: request.Response, callback: (err: Error | null, body: any) => void) => void;
type Parser = BrowserParser | NodeParser;

declare module "superagent" {
    interface ConfigurableSuperAgent<Req extends request.SuperAgentRequest> extends request.SuperAgent<Req> {
        accept(type: string): this;
        auth(user: string, name: string): this;
        buffer(val?: boolean): this;
        ca(cert: Buffer): this;
        cert(cert: Buffer | string): this;
        key(cert: Buffer | string): this;
        ok(callback: (res: Response) => boolean): this;
        on(name: 'error', handler: (err: any) => void): this;
        on(name: 'progress', handler: (event: ProgressEvent) => void): this;
        on(name: string, handler: (event: any) => void): this;
        parse(parser: Parser): this;
        pfx(cert: Buffer | string): this;
        query(val: object | string): this;
        redirects(n: number): this;
        retry(count?: number, callback?: CallbackHandler): this;
        serialize(serializer: Serializer): this;
        set(field: object): this;
        set(field: string, val: string): this;
        timeout(ms: number | { deadline?: number, response?: number }): this;
        type(val: string): this;
        use(fn: Plugin): this;
    }

    interface SuperAgentStatic extends request.SuperAgent<request.SuperAgentRequest> {
        agent(): ConfigurableSuperAgent<request.SuperAgentRequest>;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to contradict the Agents for Global State section of the docs.

Comment: How exactly? I've just checked, and mentjoned types work as expected with latest `superagent` and `@types/superagent`

Comment: TS would not allow the cast from ConfigurableSuperAgent to Request, even though it extends SuperAgent<Req>

Comment: well, the main problem is `.agent()` is supposed to return a `Request` type because those are supposed to be part of the Fluent API flow.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this, it should work as intended, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ufufke?file=index.ts . You may notice that the compiler is ok with provided types. agent() isn't supposed to return Request type because it doesn't do any request. It will return Request once there will be one, `agent().get(...)`. The question doesn't mention Fluent API and it's unclear what the problem may be. Any way, I believe that's how Superagent should be typed, because `as any` can hardly be considered a proper way to type anything in TS, it's a hack to manage untypeable things.

Comment: yeah there was a namespace collision from elsewhere in the app, this works.